# Modify Table Headings

Tags: table

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
k[R0_, m_] := m/R0
eq1[ε_, R0_, m_] := 1 + α/6 + (1/360)*k[R0, m]*R*γ*ε; 
eq2[ε_, R0_, m_] := α + (1/6)*k[R0, m]*(-k[R0, m]^3 + 2*k[R0, m]*α+R*γ) + (1/12)*k[R0, m]*R*γ*ε; 
eq3[ε_, R0_, m_] := γ + (1/6)*k[R0, m]*(-1 + k[R0, m]*γ) + (1/120)*((-k[R0, m])*(k[R0, m]^2 + α) + k[R0, m]^4*α) - (k[R0, m]^2*R*α*ε)/20160; 

data = Table[{α, γ, R}/.FindRoot[{eq1[ε, R0, m], eq2[ε, R0, m], eq3[ε, R0, m]}, {{α, 0.5}, {γ, 0.5}, {R, 1000}}, AccuracyGoal -> 8, PrecisionGoal -> 8, WorkingPrecision -> 8], {ε, 0, 5, 1}, {R0, 1, 5, 1}, {m, {3.83171, 7.01559, 10.1735, 13.3237, 16.4706, 19.6159, 22.7601}}];

FormatCells[table_] := With[{minPosition = OrderingBy[table, Last, 1]}, MapAt[Item[#, Background -> Yellow] &, TableForm[{#}, TableDirections -> Row, TableHeadings -> {None, {"ε", "R0", "m", "k", "α", "γ", "R"}}, TableSpacing -> {.8, .8}] & /@ table, minPosition]]
FormatTable[table_] := Grid[FormatCells /@ table, Dividers -> All]
FormatTable[data[[1]]]

table = First@MinimalBy[#, Last] & /@ data[[1]];
Export["Data 1.csv", table, TableHeadings -> {"ε", "R0", "m", "k", "α", "γ", "R"}]
```

How can I show the values of `ε, R0, m and k` in the output table? (image for reference: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5FL2x.png).
I have also tried `Range` in the `TableHeadings` but nothing seems to work.

Comment: Before trying to format your tables, you should address the many `FindRoot` error messages.  Then, to display values of "ε", "R0", "m", "k", be sure to include them in the output of `Table` in the desired order.

Comment: How can I include `"ε", "R0", "m", "k"` in the output of `Table`? By including them at the beginning and in the end, is still giving me errors. The values getting displayed in the output are infact `"α", "γ", "R"` and not  `"ε", "R0", "m"`.  Please help me with this

Comment: My original `eqs`, which are 100 lines long (not posted here) have no error messages due to `FindRoot`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an extended comment, redefine `data` as

```
data = Table[Flatten@{ε, R0, m, k[R0, m],{α, γ, R}/.
    FindRoot[{eq1[ε, R0, m], eq2[ε, R0, m], eq3[ε, R0, m]}, {{α, 0.5}, 
    {γ, 0.5}, {R, 1000}}, AccuracyGoal -> 8, PrecisionGoal -> 8, 
    WorkingPrecision -> 8]}, {ε, 0, 5, 1}, {R0, 1, 5, 1}, 
    {m, {3.83171, 7.01559, 10.1735, 13.3237, 16.4706, 19.6159, 22.7601}}];
```

This will, at least, provide all the quantities desired in the final table.

Comment: You're awesome! Thanks a lot.